# Can't find msbuild.exe in visual studio 2010

Tags: windows, visual-c++, msbuild

I'm trying to compile windows project from visual studio 2010 (64) on windows 7 in c++ from command line, but I can't find **msbuild.exe**, where is it?

Comment: Have you read this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415497/how-do-i-get-msbuild-exe-can-it-build-a-vcproj-when-vs2008-is-not-installed

Comment: now yes ... but that didn't told me much ...

Comment: Searched my computer, found 13 copies of `msbuild.exe`. They give 11 distinct md5 checksums. I have no idea.

Answer (score 35):

It should be installed as part of .NET 4... so for example, in

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

... but if you start a "Visual Studio Command Prompt" instead of just running cmd, it should be in the path already. That's what I'd suggest you do - I always have Visual Studio Command Prompt as a shortcut pinned to my task bar; I have no reason to launch a command prompt which *doesn't* have the relevant path :)

Comment: If the Visual Studio command prompt also fails you probably need to remove any quotes surrounding entries in your path - see http://www.blinnov.com/en/2010/06/04/microsoft-was-unexpected-at-this-time/

Comment: Command "MSBuild.exe" is not valid. from Visual Studio 2013 Command Window, file is present at proper location.

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari: Not sure what you mean by "is not valid". This should be absolutely fine...

Comment: That is the Message i get from command window. (Command "MSBuild.exe" is not valid)

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari: Have you tried executing it with an absolute path name? Is everything else working?

Comment: yes, I am providing absolute path. Solution(It have two projects if that makes any difference) is working fine as such, but I have not used Command Window before, wanted to explore that. So I have no clue if there is problem with commands.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like something is badly broken, I'm afraid - you're trying to run the 64-bit version on a 32-bit machine, or something like that. You might want to ask a new question with the details in - it's not really suitable for this question, which was just about where msbuild.exe lives.

Comment: Okay. Just to let you know, machine is 64bit.

Answer (score 8):

As of 2013 [msbuild ships with Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio.aspx):

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`

Before that msbuild shipped with the .NET Framework, up to version 4.5.1:

- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe`